# Changing time signatures

Tags: composition

As a songwriter im wanting to understand how to change the time signature/ meter of my lyrics to give them a more interesting affect? I've read many articles indicating that changing the rhythm/ meter of your lyrics can give a different affect? Can someone explain this concept from a songwriter perspective, please? Thank you!

Comment: Why on Earth would you want to do that?

Comment: You'll need to expand a lot on what it actually is you want to do here. It sounds like you want to do something odd. Explain please.

Comment: I suppose you mean to change the time of your lyrics and create a new melody.

Comment: I elaborated more on my question. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Do you really want to change the meter, or do you just want syncopation?

Answer (score 1):

I can't help specifically with song writing, but I stumbled onto this **old** video the other day, where *Mack the Knife* is played with several different time signatures -- 4/4, 3/4, 2/4, etc. If this sort of thing were done in way that was coordinated with lyrics, to be part of a single song, it could certainly have interesting effect. Perhaps listening to this -- while maybe trying to ignore the stylistic changes that are also made -- might give you some ideas. I hope it is helpful.

**ADDENDUM:** I also ran into the following link, which looked useful. Since you've probably read a lot more on the topic than I have, the content may already be familiar to you. If so, please ignore. https://www.izotope.com/en/learn/time-signatures-explained-creating-interesting-motion-with-meter-changes.html